Unable to install factory with poetry env in python 3.11
I'm trying to install factory on my poetry env but I'm getting this error:
poetry add factory

Using version ^1.2 for factory

Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (3.4s)

Package operations: 1 install, 1 update, 0 removals

  - Updating setuptools (75.1.0 -> 75.6.0)
  - Installing factory (1.2): Failed

  ChefBuildError

  Backend subprocess exited when trying to invoke get_requires_for_build_wheel
  
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/XXXX/Library/Application Support/pypoetry/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 389, in <module>
      main()
    File "/Users/XXXX/Library/Application Support/pypoetry/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 373, in main
      json_out["return_val"] = hook(**hook_input["kwargs"])
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/Users/XXXX/Library/Application Support/pypoetry/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 143, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return hook(config_settings)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/private/var/folders/rh/h9myr_6x779dbxhx7fkzrwlh0000gn/T/tmpfdlsqi07/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 334, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=[])
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/private/var/folders/rh/h9myr_6x779dbxhx7fkzrwlh0000gn/T/tmpfdlsqi07/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 304, in _get_build_requires
      self.run_setup()
    File "/private/var/folders/rh/h9myr_6x779dbxhx7fkzrwlh0000gn/T/tmpfdlsqi07/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 522, in run_setup
      super().run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
    File "/private/var/folders/rh/h9myr_6x779dbxhx7fkzrwlh0000gn/T/tmpfdlsqi07/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 320, in run_setup
      exec(code, locals())
    File "<string>", line 11, in <module>
  NameError: name 'file' is not defined. Did you mean: 'filter'?
  

  at ~/Library/Application Support/pypoetry/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/poetry/installation/chef.py:164 in _prepare
      160│ 
      161│                 error = ChefBuildError("\n\n".join(message_parts))
      162│ 
      163│             if error is not None:
    → 164│                 raise error from None
      165│ 
      166│             return path
      167│ 
      168│     def _prepare_sdist(self, archive: Path, destination: Path | None = None) -> Path:

Note: This error originates from the build backend, and is likely not a problem with poetry but with factory (1.2) not supporting PEP 517 builds. You can verify this by running 'pip wheel --no-cache-dir --use-pep517 "factory (==1.2)"'.

How can I solve this?
I haven't any issues with any other dependencies and I'm using Python 3.11.

What happens if you run the command shown at the bottom of the error message?
